# Using Captum with Stable Baselines

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I've been testing [Captum](https://captum.ai/) feature attribution with a [Stable Baselines](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) PPO agent, and I wanted to make sure I was taking the right approach. I couldn't find any tutorials for using Captum in an RL setting...

1. During an evaluation episode of the agent I'm recording observations from the environment.
2. Afterwards, I'm constructing a Captum integrated gradients object like this:

```
ig = IntegratedGradients(agent.policy.mlp_extractor.policy_net)
```

3. Then I'm choosing a target action, and, after converting the recorded observations to a tensor, providing those as inputs to the attribute method along with the initial (reset) observation as the baseline:

```
attr = ig.attribute(recorded_observations_tensor, initial_observation_tensor, action)
```

For the simple [Gymnasium](https://gymnasium.farama.org/) Cart Pole environment, that produces something like this:

```
Importances of features for action: Left
Cart position: 2.047e-05
Cart velocity: 4.940e-04
Pole angle: 4.476e-06
Pole angular velocity: 2.138e-04
```

Am I on the right track in terms of recording observations and using the policy net as the forward function?